# UIGestureRecognizer set minimum number of touches on the views superview rather than the view itself?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to make it so that the view I'm adding a pan gesture to, cannot be moved unless at least two fingers are being used on the screen. However, I don't want to require the minimum amount of touches be made on the pannable view itself, instead I want to set that minimum touches on the views superview.

Any ideas on how I should go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create the gesture recognizer and then add it to the view's superview.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *twoFingerPan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:aView action:@selector(twoFingerPanAction:)];
twoFingerPan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
[aView.superview addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerPan];
[twoFingerPan release];
```

Make sure that you have already added `aView` to its super. If this code executes before then, `aView.superview` will be `nil`, and the gesture recognizer won't work.

And, make sure that if you remove `aView` from its superview that you remove this gesture recognizer from the superview.